# Memory overflowing by using roi() function Opencv on Javascript

Tags: javascript, opencv, chromium, roi, quic

I have a camera with a double lens connected via USB to my computer and I have created an anaglyphic 3D video using OpenCV on Javascript.

The problem is, I reach an error called OutOfMemory. I have checked for leak memory from my variables that are in a loop and I could see that everyone remains with its same pointer, except one, here the code:

I had to debug and I realize that this variable changed its pointer every time the loop started again:

```
CorrIzq = dstIzq.roi(RectImgIzq);
```

So, I commented and I pass it directly on `addWeighted()` function, but now it assigned a new pointer to `dstEstereoscopico` (this is a variable Mat). So, I put it as const and seems it has the same pointer every loop, but still the memory overflow.

Can you help me, please?

Do you know if this could be a bug or maybe I'm using it wrong?

```
function processVideo() {
    begin = Date.now();
    try {
      //dstEstereoscopico = new cv.Mat(videoEstereoscopico.height - 15, videoEstereoscopico.width - 20, cv.CV_8UC1);
      console.log(dstEstereoscopico);

      //Dibujando en el objeto Canvas
      capIzq.read(srcIzq);
      capDer.read(srcDer);
      console.log(capIzq);


      //Obteniendo canales RGB
      cv.split(srcIzq, Array_rgbValores);
      Array_rgbValores.set(1, cv.Mat.zeros(canvasFrameIzq.height, canvasFrameIzq.width, cv.CV_8UC1));
      Array_rgbValores.set(2, cv.Mat.zeros(canvasFrameIzq.height, canvasFrameIzq.width, cv.CV_8UC1));
      cv.cvtColor(srcIzq, dstIzq, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
      cv.merge(Array_rgbValores, dstIzq);

      //Aplicando corrección de posicionamiento
      //CorrIzq = dstIzq.roi(RectImgIzq);
      //console.log(CorrIzq);

      cv.split(srcDer, Array_rgbValores);
      Array_rgbValores.set(0, cv.Mat.zeros(canvasFrameIzq.height, canvasFrameIzq.width, cv.CV_8UC1));
      Array_rgbValores.set(1, cv.Mat.zeros(canvasFrameIzq.height, canvasFrameIzq.width, cv.CV_8UC1));
      cv.cvtColor(srcDer, dstDer, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
      cv.merge(Array_rgbValores, dstDer);

      //CorrDer = dstDer.roi(RectImgDer);


      //corrDer = dstDer,
      cv.addWeighted(dstIzq.roi(RectImgIzq), 0.7, dstDer.roi(RectImgDer), 0.5, 1, dstEstereoscopico);
      contextDer.clearRect(0,0, canvasFrameDer.width, canvasFrameDer.height);
      contextIzq.clearRect(0,0, canvasFrameIzq.width, canvasFrameIzq.height);
      contextDestEste.clearRect(0,0, videoEstereoscopico.width, videoEstereoscopico.height);
      cv.imshow("videoEstereoscopico", dstEstereoscopico);
      // schedule next one.

      /*srcIzq.delete();
      srcDer.delete();
      dstIzq.delete();
      dstDer.delete();
      Array_rgbValores.delete();*/
      //dstEstereoscopico.delete();
      //dstEstereoscopico = [];

      //CorrIzq.delete();
      //CorrDer.delete();

      //console.log(performance.memory);
      //console.log("El contador es: " + contador++);
      //console.log("Tiempo transcurrido: " + (Date.now() - tiempoInicio)/1000 + " s");
      clearTimeout(id_SetProVid);
      delay = ((Date.now() - begin));
      id_SetProVid = setTimeout(processVideo, delay);

    } catch (err) {
      console.log("El error se ha cacheado");
      this.printError(err);
    }
  }
  setTimeout(processVideo, 0);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yesterday I solved this problem.
Actually, the problem was too these code lines:

```
Array_rgbValores.set(1, cv.Mat.zeros(canvasFrameIzq.height, canvasFrameIzq.width, cv.CV_8UC1));
Array_rgbValores.set(2, cv.Mat.zeros(canvasFrameIzq.height, canvasFrameIzq.width, cv.CV_8UC1));
```

I think this is not the wright use. However, I change them in the next way:

```
R = Array_rgbValoresIzq.get(0);
G = new cv.Mat.zeros(videoIzq.height, videoIzq.width, cv.CV_8UC1);
B = new cv.Mat.zeros(videoIzq.height, videoIzq.width, cv.CV_8UC1);
A = Array_rgbValoresIzq.get(3);

Array_rgbBuffIzq.push_back(R);
Array_rgbBuffIzq.push_back(G);
Array_rgbBuffIzq.push_back(B);
Array_rgbBuffIzq.push_back(A);
```

I had to create one new MatVector and 4 more Mats. The good news is that this solved the memory leak and it worked perfectly.